# How to import certain rows from a file using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder full of files, containing various simulation results. I am trying to to import a single row within each file into a data-frame. I have been using Pandas *read_csv* function to carry out this task. Below is the code I have been using:-

```
p32 = pd.DataFrame()
file_list = glob.glob('*.sts')


for file in file_list:  
    if p32.empty:
         p32 = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', skiprows = 9, header = 1, nrows = 1 , skip_blank_lines = True, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', skipinitialspace = True )
         itz = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[2]
         p32['Iteration'] = itz
    else:
        p32_temp = pd.read_csv(file, sep = '\t', skiprows = 9, nrows = 1, header =1 , encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', skipinitialspace = True )
        itz = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[2]
        p32_temp['Iteration'] = itz
        p32 = pd.concat([p32, p32_temp], axis = 0)
        del p32_temp
```

The problem is, I need to extract two different lines at two different index locations. The first location has the titles (index = 10), the second location contains the data (index 14). When I use the code above, I get a correct sized Dataframe, with the correct columns. However, the data inside of the dataframe is from the wrong column.

I know I need to alter the skiprows, and I know you can pass a list into this argument, but how can you ensure one of them becomes the header?

Many thanks.

MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an easier way to do this (might not be the best way). This should work.

Try this:

```
file_list = glob.glob('*.sts')
run_once = 0
for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = '\t').iloc[[10,14]]
    if run_once == 0:
        frames = df
        run_once = 1
    else:
        frames = pd.concat([frames, df])
```

Let me know if you get stuck. Happy to help !!